# System.Windows.Forms.Timer on other thread c#

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, timer

Im making a program, whenever it receives message "000000000", it will draw the graph.i try using Timer. I start Timer in Form_Load event. When it receive message "0000000"(in other Thread), i enable the timer :timer1.Enabled = true; . It works but it always draw and redraw the graph, never stop, i try to disable the timer after 1st time it finishes drawing. But when i disable the timer: timer1.Enabled =false;, it draws for the 1st time and then i receive the "0000000" message one more time(), it did not draw any more. I want it to draw only 1 time whenever it receives the "0000000" message. Please help me.   Here is my code.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Start();
}
```

I start the timer on Form_Load.

```
if (cnvertMsg == "0000000000000000" || cnvertMsg == "00000000")
{
    timer1.Enabled = true;
    isStart = true;
}
```

When message "00000000" is received, i enable the timer.This code is not in GUI Thread.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (isStart && !backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
    {
        if (!ps.ComPort.IsOpen) 
        {
            isStart = false;
            MessageBox.Show("device is disconnected!"); 
            return; 
        }
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(FormSettings.openFileName))
        {
            isStart = false;
            MessageBox.Show("pls chose your file by clicking tool!");
            return;
        }
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(FormSettings.saveFileName))
        {
            isStart = false;
            MessageBox.Show("pls chose where to save results ly clicking tool!");
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            listView1.Items.Clear();
            clearGraph();
            OnStop = false;
            Ontest = true;
            progressBar1.Maximum = ps.Step;
            progressBar1.Value = progressBar1.Minimum;

            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
            btnTest.Enabled = false;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            timer1.Enabled = false;
        }

        isStart = false;
        timer1.Enabled = false;

    }
}
```

And here is timer_tick event.

Comment: Why do you need Timer if you want to draw only once you get message?